# PHP foreach statement jumps at the end once an array spliced at its beginning

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-splice

I'm facing rather an unexpected behavior running the code below.

Here's what's happening:

Once the condition (`if ($item_key === 3 || $item_key === 7)`) is met and **Item 3** is moved to the beginning of the **$items_arr**, the *`foreach`* statement jumps to last index. Resulting in further indices, including **Item 7**, not being processed.

I would like to know what is going on internally, and why there seems to be an abort in the *`foreach`* statement once an array spliced at the beginning.

Interestingly, where is no such behavior when some arrays spliced at the end of the **$items_arr**.

Any thought is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

$items_arr = [];

// adding some items
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $items_arr[] = [
        "id" => $i,
        "name" => "Item {$i}",
    ];
}

/*
 * Some items need to be moved at the
 * beginning of the array.
 */
$i = 0;
foreach ($items_arr as $item_key => &$item)
{
    print "Processing: {$item['name']}" . PHP_EOL;

    // some condition is met
    if ($item_key === 3 || $item_key === 7)
    {
        array_splice($items_arr, $i, 0, [$item]);
        $i++;
        unset($items_arr[$item_key + $i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Processing: Item 0
Processing: Item 1
Processing: Item 2
Processing: Item 3
Processing: Item 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying `$items_arr` within the loop which de-syncs the foreach loop (that's honestly the best way I can describe it). You'll need to short-circuit the loop and start over whenever a mutation has occurred.

```
$mutated = null;
do {
    $mutated = false;
    foreach ($items_arr as $item_key => &$item)
    {
        print "Processing: {$item['name']}" . PHP_EOL;

        // some condition is met
        if ($item_key === 3 || $item_key === 7)
        {
            array_splice($items_arr, $i, 0, [$item]);
            $i++;
            unset($items_arr[$item_key + $i]);
            $mutated = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
while($mutated == true);
```